# nginx, alternative to if inside location to download or streaming a file

Tags: nginx

i have a problem. Inside nginx.conf i want to download a file only if there's in a query param "?dl=1" otherwise i want to stream the video mp4.

I have write this code:

```
 location ~\mp4 {
     if ($args_dl = "1") {
            types { application/octet-stream (.mp4); }
            default_type application/octet-stream;
     }
}
```

This code doesn't work because there's a if statement inside location. how should i change it to be able to perform the same operation? Thanks

Comment: When `nginx` evaluates the `location` block, it is looking for something to match, so make a `location` block for each action. You can nest `location` blocks.

Comment: how can i do what you said? could you give me an example?

Comment: Something like (untested) `location ~ \.mp4 { location ~ $args_dl\=1 { ... } ... }` just fill in `...` with your configuration. I think have that wrong, but it should get you going.

Comment: I have tried this: location ~/.mp4 {
                        location ~ $arg_dl\=1 {
                                types { application/octet-stream (.mp4); }
                                default_type application/octet-stream;
                        }
                }
but doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error: `location ~ \.mp4`. See if `sudo nginx -t` says anything, but it may not find this as an error.

Comment: Fix it but doesn't work.  Now is: location ~\mp4 { location ~ $args_dl\=1 { and outside the $args_dl\=1 works well but inside doesn't work. now it does not show the video but only downloads it, if i add location ~ $ args_dl \ = 1 it never enters. How can I fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124316/discussion-between-paul-and-founder-onepiecepower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use nginx `map` feature for this. Add the following to `http` level in nginx config:

```
map $arg_dl $mimetype {
    default video/mp4;
    1       application/octet-stream;
}
```

This one sets value for `$mimetype` variable based on the value of URL query argument `dl`. If `dl` is 1, mimetype is set to `application/octet-stream`, otherwise it is set to `video/mp4`.

And then use the mapped variable in `location` as follows:

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
    types {
        $mimetype mp4;
    }
    default_type $mimetype;
}
```

This is completely untested, and it is the first time using a mapped variable inside `types`.

I also improved the `location` match to explicitly match `.mp4` extension. `location ~ \mp4` could match any URL that contains `mp4`, so it can cause issues.

Comment: your solution works with any query you enter, even for example with? dl = vghdbsghdbhd and the download starts. How can I solve?

Comment: with your changes I also always download the video, whatever link I open. Allows streaming from html embed code only. How can I fix it? I would like to set that if I open the link directly it will stream and that's it. Only with a param query that I decide will I download

Comment: I want to set that if someone enters a dl other than 1 there is a redirect to a 404 error page. How can I do? Thank you